# Create two model with nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am trying to create a nested form rails in which will create two model at the same time. The model are has follow:

Model/Events

```
#Data
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :description, :locations_attributes
#Relationship
  has_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true
```

Model/Locations

```
#Data
  attr_accessible :address, :customer_id, :event_id, :latitude, :longitude
#Relationship
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :event
```

The view his like this

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :locations do |e| %>
    <%= e.hidden_field :longitude %>
    <%= e.hidden_field :latitude %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The controller looks like this

```
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @location = Location.new
    ...
  def create
    @event = current_customer.events.build(params[:event])
    @event.locations.build(params[:locations])
    respond_to do |format|
    ...
```

The issues is that when I create the events, the form is generated, it create the events and create a locations and associated to the events, but my longitude and latitude field are empty. I must note they are float type, but i don't understand why it shouldn't work

Update: I notice for me to be able to access the field_for i must change the field_for to single

```
 <%= f.fields_for :location do |e| %>
```

But then when doing this i get the following error when trying to create the event

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: location
```

and the params is has follow

```
 "location"=>{"longitude"=>"-80.9460917",
 "latitude"=>"46.4350391"}
```

This is my javascript

```
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
    function showPosition(position)
    {
        document.getElementById('event_location_latitude').value=position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('event_location_longitude').value=position.coords.longitude;
    }
```

I admits its ugly but it does the jobs from application.js I called it with a function in the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   getLocation();
  </script>
```

Which is just before <% end %> of the form

Comment: longitude and latitude are hidden fields. did you set it's value somewhere? if you never set anything for longitude and latitude it will be nil. i don't see it in the code

Comment: Yeah they are added with javascript, actually they aren't showing up if i change it to text field Ill update something

Comment: but where is it stored to? a sessions? when you do a hidden field it should be carrying over from somewhere else.

Comment: No its html5 getgeolocation, I also took that down, i updated the issue its like a circle

Comment: you need to set the value where its pulling from. look at my example below

Comment: you might want to give RubyGeoCoder a run at it if this doesn't work out. it's also on railscast episode #273. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

if you have questions after viewing it. let me know

In your hidden field code you need to set a value. For example.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :song_id, value: params[:id] %>
<%= f.hidden_field :paid_price,  value: @song.price %>
```

Comment: I have checked it out, its the same has me but its not working

Comment: The values of latitude and longitude do get passed, i show whats get passed

Comment: in the above example. you are grabbing data from value: @song.price and saving it to :paid_price.

Comment: you need to do the same with your hidden fields. you are not pointing it to any value that is why it is nil

Comment: Yeah well after the page is loaded i call the function getLocations and grab the elementById to then set the value of the hidden value, but its done in javascript and i admits its ugly, but if i change to text_field just for testing purpose, i see the value like -45.6666... and then submit it, the parameters been sent see it

Comment: I just updated the code to see how i place value in the hidden field

Comment: but you're not making the connection to your backend. you can "see" it but it's not passing it. If you do have it then it's very simple whatever instance variable you set you need to put in.

Comment: i see that you're pulling the info on javascript. The problem is that it's only displaying it in the view. It's not being stored anywhere. can you specifically tell me what it is store into? as I've said before just having e.hidden field :longitude does nothing. nothing gets store in there

Comment: Longitude and Latitude are field set for the model Locations, they should talk to each other

Comment: you can try this:<%= hidden_field_tag 'token' %>                   function token_generated(e, token)
{
  $('#stripeform input[type=hidden]').val(token.id);
}
                                something to that effect. not sure if it wil work

Comment: Well this solve the issues of me been able to send data, but at the same time it doesn't store it in my location new records. Really start doubting about rails

Answer (score 0):

do you put :location in your attr_accessible? cz the error u show is can't mass assign for your location

Comment: In event model i have this line attr_accessible :customer_id, :description, :locations_attributes and in my location i have this attr_accessible :address, :customer_id, :event_id, :latitude, :longitude

Comment: can you try this?? 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations_attributes, :allow_destroy => true  which in your event model

Comment: Getting this error No association found for name `locations_attributes'. Has it been defined yet?

Comment: because in this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1, It mentioned,If you are protecting attributes with attr_accessible be certain to add the nested attributes to that (such as questions_attributes and answers_attributes). , so probably i guess this might be your problem

Comment: In this case in my model events I have the following locations which is , :locations_attributes. If i miss something else i am not sure

Comment: use Ajax and setup a controller in your app to handle JSON POST requests/responses